# My dataframe saved as a csv file adds a new column automatically when I read the same file immediately

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

Here is a simple example.

I have created a dataframe
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10,3)),columns=['a','b','c'])`

saved it down to my folder 
`df.to_csv('testing.csv')`

but as soon as I read the same file 
`df = pd.read_csv('testing.csv)`

it seems to be adding a new column automatically. Does anyone know what's happening here?

```
   Unnamed: 0  a  b  c
0           0  4  5  6
1           1  1  5  1
2           2  8  6  2
3           3  7  9  7
4           4  3  2  6
5           5  9  1  2
6           6  4  1  3
7           7  3  3  3
8           8  5  3  7
9           9  4  3  8
```

Comment: `np.random.randint(1,10,(10,3)`

Comment: That is likely the index. Call ```to_csv``` with parameter ```index=False``` if you don't want to save the index.

Comment: @EricTruett thanks, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: when you read a `CSV` file there would be a column `index` in you `datafram`, saving it and open again again you would have `index` column,use `index=False` when reading file

Answer (score 2):

An extra column in added while loading the csv because you are saving file with the index, that is the default index of the dataframe

add `index=False` while saving

```
df.to_csv('testing.csv', index=False)
```